# Second Javascript function throws everything off

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I just have a simple javascript code in which I animate elements to appear on the page when the page loads. Everything is fine with the animating segment. However, when I try to add in a second javascript command for when I hover over the image, nothing else works. I am definitely sure it has to do with how I entered the code. Can someone help fix my code?

```
var main = function() {
    {
        $(".menu").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 400);
    };

    {
        $(".about h2").animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, 500);

    }; {
        $(".about p").animate({
            "bottom": "0px"
        }, 580);

    }; {
        $(".resume").animate({
            "bottom": "0px"
        }, 650);

    }; {
        $("#image img").animate({
            "right": "0px"
        }, 600);

    };
    $("#image img").hover(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "background-color:"
            "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
        });
    });


}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: There's no reason to encase every statement in its own `{ }` block.

Comment: Also the first thing to do is check the developer console for errors.

Comment: Can you show us the html?

Comment: In an object literal `{key: value, key2: value2, ... }` the key can be in quotes, the value is in quotes when it is a string literal, but the colon `:` never should be in quotes.  After removing that typo in the object literal supplied to `$(this).css({...})`, are there any other errors reported in the error console? You can see the error console with control shift J or F12.

Comment: @Pointy yes I have removed the {} and they work without adding the second function. However, upon adding the hover function again, the code ceases to work. Paul I don't think that your comment answers the question in any way, but thanks for the input. :)

Comment: @Paul it does however say Uncaught syntax error: Unexpected token in the error console

Comment: Possibly it was expecting a `:` but saw a `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is incorrect:

```
    $(this).css({
        "background-color:"
        "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    });
```

That's just two strings, not separated in any way, and therefore not a valid object. The correct syntax is `propertyName : "value"`, so your code should be

```
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    });
```

[**See the docs**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for more info.

Also, as others have pointed out, you don't need all those `{...}` blocks. Your code can be simplified to this:

```
var main = function() {
        $(".menu").animate({
            "top": "0px"
        }, 400);
    };

$(".about h2").animate({
    "right": "0px"
}, 500);

$(".about p").animate({
    "bottom": "0px"
}, 580);

$(".resume").animate({
    "bottom": "0px"
}, 650);

$("#image img").animate({
    "right": "0px"
}, 600);

$("#image img").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"
    });
});

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: This has helped! Thank you guys!